# libcamera installation not working on "meson setup build"

Tags: libcamera

I am using Lubuntu on a Raspberry Pi 3B and trying to install libcamera following the instructions here:

https://libcamera.org/getting-started.html

After downloading the libcamera.git repository and running

```
meson setup build
```

I get the message:

> ```
> Error during basic setup:
>
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/robot/Downloads/libcamera/setup'
> ```

In the downloaded repository, there is not setup or build folder, which seems to be what meson is looking for. The directory tree:

```
Documentation/
include/
LICENSES
package/
src/
subprojects/
test/
utils/
COPYING.rst
meson.build
meson_options.txt
README.rst
```

Is it trying to look for a setup or build folder somewhere else that I need to add into the PATH variable? Or are the instructions outdated for this repository?